# no sound when using pjsip

Tags: ios, audio, call, pjsip

I've got a problem with pjsip. I'm trying to make an outgoing call with pjsua_call_make_call. It's working, but when I answer this call on a device, I can't hear any sound. However, I can see an icon on iPhone, indicating that a microphone is in use. Did anybody come across such issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue. I place an outbound call and I can hear the audio on the device when I pick up the call, but can't hear any audio on the device using pjsip to make the call.

If your audio capture doesn't seem to be working make sure you have microphone permission, and you have to manually call `pjsua_set_snd_dev()`, when you connect. There's some other additional troubleshooting here https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#Commonproblems

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with iOS, but I suppose you should connect audio stream to some device in `on_call_media_state` callback ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__callback.htm#a22f1ccccb145176fef945cc34ca6685f)). Look at minimal example from desktop app:

```
pjsua_call_info ci;
pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);

for (unsigned i = 0; i < ci.media_cnt; i++) {
    if (ci.media[i].type == PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        if (ci.media[i].status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE) {
            pjsua_conf_connect(ci.conf_slot, 0);
            pjsua_conf_connect(0, ci.conf_slot);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
iOS code for default audio stream in call:

```
var callinfo: pjsua_call_info = pjsua_call_info()
pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &callinfo)
if(callinfo.media_status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE) {
    pjsua_conf_connect(callinfo.conf_slot, 0)
    pjsua_conf_connect(0, callinfo.conf_slot)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was solved by the fact that I changed the device to which the call was going. On the previous device, the on_call_media_state call was not working correctly.